# Moving A Rectangle in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game and encountered a problem... I cant move the rectangle, and it doesn't give me an error code either?.. I think the problem is that it keeps making the rectangle over and over again in the while loop... but I don't know how to fix this..

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import random
import pygame
import math
import sys

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("LEVEL 2 = Find the Correct Square!")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), (64, 54, 16, 16))

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
           self.rect.move(-1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
           self.rect.move(1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
           self.rect.move(0, -1)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
           self.rect.move(0, 1)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), (64, 54, 16, 16))

pygame.init()

player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True       
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
            running = False

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

        player.draw(screen)
        player.handle_keys()
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(40)
```

Comment: `self.rect = pygame.Rect(start_x, start_y, width, height)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make a few changes to your `Player` class. You either need to reassign `self.rect` to the result of `self.rect.move()` or use the inplace variant `self.rect.move_ip()`

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((64, 54, 16, 16))

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
           self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
           self.rect.move_ip(1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, 1)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)
```

The rectangle will move once for each keypress. If you want to keep moving when you hold a key down, you need to dedent part of your main loop

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
            running = False

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    player.draw(screen)
    player.handle_keys()
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(40)
```

Answer (score 1):

`move` simply returns a new rectangle without altering the variable, so use `move_ip` to move in place.

```
pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 128), self.rect) # draw the rect at a variable location
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code so that 1) it works (essential! :)  and 2) one can exit from the script with [Esc] and QUIT, and not get stuck in it (also essential!) I also gave life to your 'dist' variable (which was not used) to set displacements of 10 pixels. Yet, there are still important things to be added, e.g. checking for and preventing the small rectangle getting out of the window, etc.

```
import os
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * # Constants
import math
import sys

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("LEVEL 2 = Find the Correct Square!")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), (64, 54, 16, 16))
        self.dist = 10

    def handle_keys(self):
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); exit()
            elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
                key = e.key
                if key == K_LEFT:
                    self.draw_rect(-1, 0)
                elif key == K_RIGHT:
                    self.draw_rect(1, 0)
                elif key == K_UP:
                    self.draw_rect(0, -1)
                elif key == K_DOWN:
                    self.draw_rect(0, 1)
                elif key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit(); exit()

    def draw_rect(self,x,y):
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.rect.move(x*self.dist, y*self.dist); pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)
        pygame.display.update()

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), (64, 54, 16, 16))

pygame.init()

player = Player()
#clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
player.draw(screen)
pygame.display.update()

while True:
  player.handle_keys()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import random
import pygame
import math
import sys

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("LEVEL 2 = Find the Correct Square!")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), (64, 54, 16, 16))

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
           self.rect.move(-1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
           self.rect.move(1, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
           self.rect.move(0, -1)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
           self.rect.move(0, 1)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), (64, 54, 16, 16))

pygame.init()

player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True       
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
            running = False

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

        player.draw(screen)
        player.handle_keys()
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(40)import os
```

Comment: Seems to be a rather long answer to a simple question. Please limit the answer to just the question asked.